# private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use domainatrix with nokogiri and am coming up with a holdup. Being relatively new to ruby, I've tried every syntax variation on the Domainatrix.parse function I can to get the a href's to parse properly. They do print during the "puts" command but when I uncomment the domainatrix code problems start:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'domainatrix'
require 'anemone'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.cnn.com"))
doc.xpath('//a/@href').each do |node|

  linkage = node.text

  puts linkage

  url = Domainatrix.parse(linkage)
  print url.domain
  print url.public_suffix

end
```

Anyone have any ideas on this? I think it is just a syntax issue or perhaps I cannot use the Domainatrix function where I'm using it?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack of the NoMethodError in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was getting snagged on some improperly formatted URLs.