# What monkeypatch creates the private method split?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

The questions [Ruby: Private method called for 3:Fixnum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697282/ruby-private-method-called-for-3fixnum) and [private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404932/private-method-split-called-for-nilnilclass-nomethoderror) mention private methods `split` for `Fixnum` and `NilClass` objects respectively.

Is this private `split` method a monkeypatched pseudo-keyword (like `print` and `puts`)? If so, what added it, and why did they use a method name that already exists for `String`?

Comment: print and puts are not "pseudo-keywords". They are just methods. I am not familiar with any gem or library that adds #split to NilClass, so I can't comment directly on that. Perhaps you can do some forensics to figure out what library is monkey-patching NilClass to add a private #split method (which is rather strange).

Comment: `split` comes from Kernel as [DigitalRoss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697282/ruby-private-method-called-for-3fixnum/5697293#5697293) notes. Then, presumably, Fixnum and NilClass provide their own private overrides to, essentially, remove `split` from their interface.

Comment: @mu is too short: D'Oh! Don't know why I didn't notice that - maybe it was posted / added after I'd already read that question. Should I merely close the question, or delete it?

Comment: Just close or delete it and blame it on a Sunday hangover :) Or I could post an answer with some code so we can fight over indentation.

Comment: @mu is too short: No need - I just earned the Copy Editor badge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this yourself (even without reading the other answer):

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :001> 3.method(:split)
#=> #<Method: Fixnum(Kernel)#split>
```

You can see from my [Ruby Method Lookup Flow](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png) ([PDF version](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.pdf)) that methods for all objects finish at the instance methods of `Object`…which itself includes `Kernel`. Thus, all instance methods of `Kernel` (added many cases to be available as top-level convenience methods) also end up as methods on every object.

Note that this is not true in 1.9+ as `Kernel#split` has been removed:

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 :001> 3.method(:split)
#=> NameError: undefined method `split' for class `Fixnum'
#=>     from (irb):1:in `method'
#=>     from (irb):1
#=>     from /Users/phrogz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```